# How to reorder a sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
RecNo | TaskDesc | SeqNumber
1     |  test    | 1
2     |  test2   | 2
3     |  test3   | 3
```

These items can be moved around using a reorder-able grid so test 3 can become SeqNumber 1 and test can become SeqNumber2. Im try to find a way to pass the new position and record number of taskDesc to a stored procedure and have it set the new position and adjust the other items. I have been somewhat successful but sometimes the numbers don't get updated. Here is a sample of what I have been trying

```
Update tblTasks Set SeqNum = SeqNum + 1
Where SeqNum >= @newPosition 
AND SeqNum < (Select SeqNum From tblTasks WHERE RecNo = @UpdatedRecNo)    

Update tblTasks Set SeqNum = @newPosition 
Where RecNo = @UpdatedRecNo
```

The problem is depending on how you move the rows the numbers can end up like this:

```
RecNo | TaskDesc | SeqNumber
    1     |  test    | 3
    2     |  test2   | 2
    3     |  test3   | 2
```

or

```
RecNo | TaskDesc | SeqNumber
    1     |  test    | 4
    2     |  test2   | 5
    3     |  test3   | 2
```

The don't stay within the bounds of 1,2,3 and do not remain unique. The SeqNum is used to represent urgency 1 being the highest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to deal with moves up differently then moves down:

```
--Store the old value for performance and to simplify code.
DECLARE @oldPosition int;
SELECT @oldPosition = SeqNum FROM tblTasks WHERE RecNo = @UpdatedRecNo;

UPDATE tblTasks
SET SeqNum = CASE
    WHEN RecNo = @UpdatedRecNo THEN @newPosition    --Put the record in the new position.
    WHEN @newPosition < @oldPosition AND SeqNum >= @newPosition AND SeqNum < @oldPosition THEN SeqNum + 1   --Move the other rows out of the way when moving to a lower position.
    WHEN @newPosition > @oldPosition AND SeqNum <= @newPosition AND SeqNum > @oldPosition THEN SeqNum - 1   --Move the other rows out of the way when moving to a higher position.
    ELSE SeqNum --No change.
    END;
```

This will pass over all of the records once and either:
 - Move it to the new sequence.
 - Move it to a higher sequence (if the moving record is moving down).
 - Move it to a lower sequence (if the moving record is moving up).
 - Leave it where it is.

If you do not want to touch all of the records, you can add:

```
WHERE   (@newPosition < @oldPosition AND SeqNum >= @newPosition AND SeqNum <= @oldPosition)
    OR  (@newPosition > @oldPosition AND SeqNum <= @newPosition AND SeqNum >= @oldPosition);
```

This would remove the need for the else clause.

Comment: Perfect thank you very much. I had a feeling I was going to need to add some kind of case thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If your table is small, it might be better just to take a brute force approach:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by (case when RecNo = @UpdatedRecNo then @newPosition + 0.5 else seqnumber end)) as newseqnumber
      from tblTasks t
     )
update toupdate
     set seqnumber = newseqnumber
     where seqnumber <> newseqnumber;
```

Comment: You are missing a `)`.  Also, this does not seem to work.  In a set of 5 records, moving Record # 2 to SeqNum 4, it is moved to 3 instead.

Comment: @Trisped . . . This should work.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle illustrating the problem?

Comment: I just tried but [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/661e62) keeps erroring out.  Let me know if you can see the code from that link.  If not then we can create a chat and put it there.  The important code: `DECLARE @newPosition int = 4;
 DECLARE @UpdatedRecNo int = 2;` with tblTasks having 5 items.

Comment: @Trisped . . . No, that fiddle doesn't have the code.

Comment: Created the [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30801/discussion-about-how-to-reorder-a-sql-table-http-stackoverflow-com-questions-33) room and added the code.

Comment: I think the issue was the `- 0.5` which I changed to `+ 0.5`.  Here is a SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9221f/2.

Comment: The update works moving #2 to position 4, but not for #4 to position 2 (which worked before).  If you have anything else to add, please add it to the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30801/discussion-about-how-to-reorder-a-sql-table-http-stackoverflow-com-questions-33) with @Trisped and I will get an alert.