# Move numbers in mysql rows for sorting

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Im in the developing of an app that has a drag and drop tableview.
When you drag and drop it resorts the table. My problem now is the SQL part of it.

I have a table like:

```
id    | item     | sortingId
3     |  test    | 1
1     |  test2   | 2
2     |  test3   | 3
8     |  test4   | 4
5     |  test5   | 5
6     |  test6   | 6
4     |  test7   | 7
7     |  test8   | 8
```

For example - I want to move "test2" down to the place between "test5" and  "test6".
Now it should look like this:

```
id    | item     | sortingId
3     |  test    | 1
2     |  test3   | 2
8     |  test4   | 3
5     |  test5   | 4
1     |  test2   | 5
6     |  test6   | 6
4     |  test7   | 7
7     |  test8   | 8
```

I found and tried to use the answer form this: [How to reorder a sql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33293505/how-to-reorder-a-sql-table)

But I not really experienced with SQL and can't make it work.

Here's what i´ve tried:

```
$sql0 = "SET @old = 2";
$sql1 = "SET @new = 5";
$sql2 = "SET @id = (SELECT id FROM items WHERE sortingId = @old)";
$sql3 = "UPDATE items SET sortingId = 0 WHERE id = @id";
$sql4 = "UPDATE items SET sortingId = sortingId + sign(@old - @new) WHERE sortingId BETWEEN least(@old, @new) AND greatest(@old, @new)";
$sql5 = "UPDATE items SET sortingId = @new WHERE id = @id";

$sql = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql0);
$sql = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql1);
$sql = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql2);
$sql = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql3);
$sql = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql4);
$sql = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql5);
```

My table is called items

Comment: So sortingId=2 will be gone? Can we just sort it again from 1->8?

Comment: No all items should be kept, just rearranged :)

Comment: Sorry, I did a wrong example. I've updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have three bits of information (I see you use them as SQL variables, but I'll use PHP variables for the moment):

```
$UpdatedRecNo = 1; // id of the record that is moving
$oldPosition = 2;  // current position for the record
$newPosition = 5;  // position the record needs to move to
```

This can be done with two simple UPDATE queries, after you check *which direction* the record is moving in:

```
if ($oldPosition < $newPosition) {
    // record is moving from position 2 to position 5, so
    // sortingIds 3, 4 and 5 need to become 2, 3 and 4
    $sql1 = "UPDATE items
             SET    sortingId = sortingId - 1
             WHERE  sortingId > $oldPosition
             AND    sortingId <= $newPosition";
} else {
    // record is moving from position 5 to position 2, so
    // sortingIds 2, 3 and 4 need to become 3, 4 and 5
    $sql1 = "UPDATE items
             SET    sortingId = sortingId + 1
             WHERE  sortingId >= $newPosition
             AND    sortingId < $oldPosition";
}

$sql2 = "UPDATE items SET sortingId = $newPosition WHERE id = $UpdatedRecNo";
```

Having your logic in PHP and performing two simple UPDATE queries seems like a lot less work than dynamically declaring SQL variables.

If, for some reason, you end up in a situation where this code is reached on a record that isn't moving at all (`$oldPosition` and `$newPosition` are the same), then `$sql1` won't have any matches (e.g. `sortingId >= 2 AND sortingId < 2` will never match) and `$sql2` will have no affected rows, so you're good.

> **Disclaimer:** Obviously, if these variables come from user input, please use prepared statements for both queries. Since I was just giving an example of how to do it with two queries, I didn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```sql
start transaction;

set @old = 2;
set @new = 5;
set @id = (select id from items where sortingId = @old);

update items
set sortingId = 0
where id = @id;

update items
set sortingId = sortingId + sign(@old - @new)
where sortingId between least(@old, @new) and greatest(@old, @new);

update items
set sortingId = @new
where id = @id;

commit;
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/TUG60933

It works in both directions (eg. you can change the position from 5 to 2).

If `sortingId` is not UNIQUE, you can skip the first UPDATE statement (`set sortingId = 0`).

Note that this is not concurrency save.

Comment: Thank you so much! But I can't get it to work. See my update under "heres what I've tried". Did I do it correct?